# What's Different Between These Two Tests (one fails, one passes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

Here is the passing test:

```
test "should create user" do
        assert_difference('User.count') do
        post :create, user: { name: "John Doe", 
                              email: "example@example.com",
                              password: "foobar3",
                              password_confirmation: "foobar3" }
end
```

And here is the failing test:

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "John Doe", 
               email: "example@example.com",
               password: "foobar3",
               password_confirmation: "foobar3")
end


test "should create user" do
        assert_difference('User.count') do
        post :create, user: @user 
end
```

Why does the second test fail? and how can I make it use the @user variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.attributes` method to get a hash of just the user's attributes, so you send those along instead of the actual user object.

```
test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
    post :create, user: @user.attributes
end
```